# Rails: How can I dynamically load from db into a bootstrap accordion only if it opens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using the 
[Awesome Nested Set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/wiki/Awesome-nested-set-cheat-sheet#basic-usage) gem to create a hierarchy now I want to display this hierarchy.

I have an index page with a typical controller action

klasses_controller.rb

```
def index
   @klasses = Klass.where(depth: 0).order('lft ASC')
end
```

klasses/index.rb

```
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <% @klasses.each do |klass| %>
        <%= render :partial => "klass", locals: {klass: klass} %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

in my index action I am calling a partial

klasses/_klass.html.erb

```
<div class="klass">
    <div class="klass-header" role="tab" id="heading-<%=klass.id%>">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" 
           data-parent="#accordion" 
           href="#collapse-<%=klass.id%>" 
           aria-expanded="false" 
           aria-controls="collapse-<%=klass.id%>">

           <%= klass.symbol + " : " + klass.title%>
        </a>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse-<%=klass.id%>" 
        class="collapse" 
        role="tabpanel" 
        aria-labelledby="heading-<%=klass.id%>">

      <div class="klass-block">
         <Here is where I want to render partial for each child>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is standard accordion and is working as is. Here is the problem I have a very big db and I don't want to render anything unnecessarily. I want to wait until the header is clicked and then asynchronously retrieve the children of the class i clicked and render each using the same partial.

How can I achieve this? Is there a way using a route/controller action combination or should I start writing coffee/java-script? I am not trying to reinvent the wheel so if anyone knows of an example that would be welcome.

Comment: How about having a link to expand each child in the `<Here is where I want to render partial for each child>` area. The link is an ajax request to show the child, which renders the same partial `_klass.html.erb` and replaces the link with the partial. The newly rendered child will of course have ajax links to expand any children it has of its own.

Comment: If I did that I would want to load at least the child's name for each of the links. In which case I would have to load the children of the root nodes in the initial index action right? Could I have the link in the header pull double duty calling for the children and opening the collapse panel.

Comment: Yes you could load the children names of the root nodes (and their id too for the path to the link) in the initial index action. Another option might be to just have a generic "Expand Children" link or button if you didn't want to fetch all the children's names. Yes you could also expand the accordion at the same time as part of the AJAX response that inserts the new data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a tricky problem only because there were a lot of moving parts. It was a real headscratcher but in hindsight it is pretty straight forward.

First I wanted to use a custom controller action so I added a route for my "children" method which is set up to receive an ajax call.

routes.rb

```
get 'klasses/:id/children', to: 'klasses#children', as: 'children_of'
```

klasses_controller.rb

```
def index
    @klasses = Klass.where(depth: 0).order('lft ASC')
end

def children
  respond_to do |format| 
      format.js {render 'children', :klass => @klass }
  end
end
```

This respond block is expecting to have a children.js.erb to call for.

children.js.erb

```
$("#collapse-<%=@klass.id%>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'klasses/children',    locals: { :klass => @klass })%>");
```

This is where we specify the div that we are going to insert the new content into and we call another partial.

_children.html.erb

```
<div class="child-block">
    <% children = @klass.children %>
    <% children.each do |child| %>
         <%= render :partial => 'klasses/klass', locals: { :klass => child } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Finally I rewrote my _klass.html.erb partial so It has a link in the heading that will both trigger bootstrap's accordion js and call our new controller action.

_klass.html.erb

```
<div class="klass">
    <div class="klass-header" role="tab" id="heading-<%=klass.id%>">
      <h5 class="mb-0">

    <%= link_to klass.symbol + " : " + klass.title,
                children_of_path(klass.id), 
                remote: true,
                :data => {  :toggle => "collapse", 
                            :parent => "#accordion",
                            :target => "#collapse-#{klass.id}"

                },
                :aria => {  :expanded => "false", 
                            :controls => "collapse-#{klass.id}"
                }%>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapse-<%=klass.id%>" 
        class="collapse" 
        role="tabpanel" 
        aria-labelledby="heading-<%=klass.id%>">

    </div>
</div>
```

That's pretty much it. Add some padding to the child-block and you have yourself a nice indented Hierarchy that dynamically loads content.

I did have to disable cross site Request forgery for my custom action in my controller

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :children
```

If anyone knows a way around that let me know.